# Apache/PHP + LibreOffice

Tags: php, apache, centos, permission-denied, libreoffice

I've installed the LibreOffice RPMS (have tried both 3.5.3 and 3.4.6) on my CentOS machine, and I'm trying to make PHP run a shell script that calls LibreOffice. In the shell script, it runs executes this line:

```
/opt/libreoffice3.4/program/soffice --headless -convert-to $extension.pdf "$1" -outdir $folder
```

However, this command will cause the following message to appear:

```
./createpdf.sh: line 8: /opt/libreoffice3.4/program/soffice: Permission denied
```

The line itself is fine. If I echo it and run it manually in SSH, it works fine. This is most likely because I'm running it as a different user (note: not as the user that installed it, and not as root), with different permissions.

Desperate as I was, I've already tried chmodding the entire libreoffice folder to 777, and tried to make the 'apache' user the owner. No luck there. Would anyone have a clue as to why it's not letting apache run it, and how I can solve this?

Comment: do you want to make pdf through php?

Comment: and what permissions have the `$folder` output folder?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to running from the command line, have you considered running UNO (the Open/Libre Office alternative to COM) with the [PUNO](http://www.wstech2.net/index.php?do=0a,01,05) PHP wrapper. That way, you don't need to worry about permissions

Answer (score 1):

See also [Universal Network Objects (UNO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Network_Objects): there are Python, Java, etc. bridges for use it.  There are applications for simplify the use for convertions, see [Docvert](http://holloway.co.nz/docvert/) and  *JODConverter* ([jODconverter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jodconverter) and [pyODconverter](https://github.com/mirkonasato/pyodconverter)).

All of then can be called as web-service or exec by PHP.